# How to check whether a pdf file exists from url?

Tags: php, html, file, pdf, file-get-contents

I am trying to check whether an arXiv url, of the form

> http://arxiv.org/pdf/[some 4 digit number].[some 4 digit number].pdf

is a pdf file or html page.  My function currently looks like

```
function is_url_exist($url){
    $ch = curl_init($url);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if($code == 200){
       $status = "true";
    }else{
      $status = "false";
    }
    curl_close($ch);
   return $status;
}
```

The problem is that the function returns false for both http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.0102.pdf whichs a pdf file and http://arxiv.org/pdf/1217.2314.pdf whichs a html page. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Well you could start dumping `$code` before `if` statement so you can see what you're actually getting from this. Did you do it?

Comment: I got 403 for both cases, does this number mean something?

Comment: [There you go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403), then.

Comment: @AedixRhinedale, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: If you are receiving 403 Forbidden, it means you lack authorization to access that content. You won't get anything if you can't access data from that location. Get authorized and then get back to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check the extension?

```
<?PHP 
if(strtolower(substr($url, -3, 3)) == "pdf"){
    // Do something with pdf
} else {
    // Not pdf
} 
?>
```

Comment: He (oddly) gave an example where the URL showed .pdf extension which was html document.